# Slim output name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

Is there a way to define the preprocessed output html name on the slim file not being the same as the slim file?

Answer (score 1):

When you generate a controller with `rails g controller Controller_name Controller_action` you create files that match the `Controller_name` part.

Within the controller a method will be created with the name of `Controller_action` e.g.

`rails g controller Home index` creates the controller:
Within the index method you'll want to render your custom template by giving render the path to your template slim file.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        #in here you'll want to render your template
        #if no render call is given, the default home.html.slim will be rendered within the views
        render 'path/to/view.html.slim'
    end
end
```

Resource: [render - Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)